# Filtering HBase Scan

Tags: hbase

How can I filter `scan` by two values, (the values associated with the columns `account_id` and `timestamp`), from a single column family - `MetaDetails`?

I have referenced this [Cloudera document](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.2/topics/admin_hbase_filtering.html#xd_583c10bfdbd326ba-7dae4aa6-147c30d0933--7c9e__section_lch_1wv_ls), but I don't see a clear way to accomplish the aforementioned.